# Flattening multi-band raster to single-band raster in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, imagery, raster-conversion

I need to convert a multi-band PNG image into a single-band raster, for analysis and visualisation.

How can I do this in ArcGIS Desktop 10.2?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found this good discussion at http://www.cartotalk.com/index.php?showtopic=7109 and thought it would be useful to add to GIS.stackexchange for posterity.

- in ArcMap 10.2, choose > Windows > Image Analysis
- in the top panel, select the input image
- in the Processing section, choose the first tool (Clip)
- this adds a new temporary raster to the TOC
- right-click this temporary raster and choose > Properties
- choose the Functions tab
- right-click on the Clip Function and choose > Insert > Grayscale Function

[image]

- right-click on the layer and choose > Data > Export Data to save this image permanently

Comment: Nice tip. Note that it is already available in ArcGIS 10.1

Answer (score 5):

Suggestion from Stephen Lead is sufficient for grayscaled rasters but not for coloured rasters (e.g. DOF). If you want to preserve the colours (conversion is quite good) then use Copy Raster tool and select RGB to Colormap option (by default is unselected). Your result will be a single band coloured image. The output will be quite good approximation of the original image and smaller in size than original.