# Calculating number of pixels in raster image using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, raster-calculator, python-2.7

I have a formula for suitability which I have created and I need to count how many pixels are in each class.

For example
- Suitability class 0 has 12545 pixels
- Suitability class 1 has 386 pixels
- Suitability class 2 has 1145 pixels
- Suitability class 3 has 518 pixels

Is there a python code for this????

By the way my program is set up because I am creating a tool(Beginning Stages). No Numpy allowed!

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

# Workspace location
env.workspace = arcpy.GetParametersAsText(0)

# DEM raster dataset
DEM = arcpy.GetParametersAsText(1)

# Land Use raster dataset
landUse = arcpy.GetParametersAsText(2)

#Floating point values of suitability weights
weight_1 = arcpy.GetParametersAsText(3)
weight_2 = arcpy.GetParametersAsText(4)
if ((weight_1 + weight_2 > 1.0),(weight_1 + weight_2 < 1)):
arcpy.AddMessage("Error! Weights limits not appropriate!")

# The output feature class name
outputFC = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(5)

# Get Slope of DEM raster
arcpy.sa.Slope(DEM, Slope_DEM,"DEGREE", "1")
arcpy.AddMessage("Slope Raster Created!")

# Reclassify Slope
reclass_slp = RemapRange([[0,3,3],[3,6,2],[6,90,1]])
reclass_slope = Reclassify(Slope_DEM, "VALUE", reclass_slp)
reclass_slope.save(workspace)
arcpy.AddMessage("Slope Raster Reclassified!")

# Get Aspect of DEM raster
outAspect = arcpy.sa.Aspect(DEM)
outAspect.save = (workspace)
arcpy.AddMessage("Aspect Raster Created!")

# Reclassify Aspect
reclass_aspt = RemapRange([[-1,0,3],[0,45,1],[45,135,2],[135,225,3],[225,315,2],[315,360,1]])
reclass_slope = Reclassify(Aspect_DEM, "VALUE", reclass_aspt)
reclass_aspt.save = (workspace)                          
arcpy.AddMessage("Aspect Raster Reclassified!")

# Reclassify Land Use Raster
reclass_land = arcpy.sa.Con(landUse,1, "Value == 18,21,73" )
reclass_land.save = (workspace) 
arcpy.AddMessage("Land Use Raster Reclassified!")

# Calculate Best Site and create resulting shapefile raster with interger values between 0 and 3
bestSite = (int((weight_1 * reclass_slp) + (weight_2 * reclass_aspt))* reclass_land)
arcpy.AddMessage("Suitability Raster Created!")
```

Comment: Convert to polygon, no line simplification. Area/cellize is your answer

Answer (score 5):

You should already have the pixel count in your integer raster attribute table. If not, run [Build Raster Attribute Table tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/build-raster-attribute-table.htm).

[image]

Then, it's just a matter of reading the table with an arcpy.da.SearchCursor.

```
my_raster = 'raster.tif'
my_dict = {row[0]:row[1] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(my_raster,['Value','Count'])}
print my_dict

{0: 6518422.0, 1: 2182076.0, 2: 2495061.0, 3: 3982945.0}
```

Comment: When attempting to build the raster attribute table, I get the error message "only single band integer raster is a valid input". The output raster from my raster calculator does not provide an attribute table.

Comment: See @Damijan's answer here for converting multiband to singleband raster: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/91403/how-can-i-flatten-a-multi-band-raster-to-a-single-band-raster-in-arcmap-10-2. Which raster in your example are you trying to summarize?

Comment: arcpy.gp.RasterCalculator_sa("(weight_1 * \"%reclassify_sp%\" + weight_2 * \"%reclassify_at%\") * \"%reclass_land%\"", outputFC)

Comment: That looks like you're trying to output a feature class. Raster Calculator outputs a raster. And what are the '%' for? That looks like model builder syntax.

Comment: I did use model builder. The result should be a raster with an attribute table i can view and get the count of. I'm just now sure where I went wrong.

Answer (score 3):

An easy way for an integer raster would be to convert it into a numpy array.

Here an arcpy approach.

```
import numpy, arcpy
raster_numpy_array = arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray("raster.tif")

# where 1 is your value
cnt_value_1 = numpy.count_nonzero(raster_numpy_array==1)
```

Here a non arcpy approach with TIFF file:

```
from scipy import misc
from PIL import Image
Image.MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS = 1000000000   # to allow big tif
raster_numpy_array = scipy.misc.imread('raster.tif')

# where 1 is your value
cnt_value_1 = numpy.count_nonzero(raster_numpy_array==1)
```

If you have a float integer, convert you array to a integer (8 ,16 bits.) with Copy Raster (Data Management).

Comment: not allowed to use numpy

Comment: @A_Worthy If you are not allowed to use NumPy then that should be mentioned in your question.